# Passing user enetered value in widget: number of words, for example

Tags: functions, widgets, widget-text

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

The above is the code snippet from one of the widgets of my theme.

Now in the widget arrangement, this is the situation →

```
$instance['number_of_words']     = absint( $new_instance['number_of_words'] );
```

the above setting is to handle how many numbers of words do we wish to show in the title?

how should we pass this variable  `$instance['number_of_words']` →

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: how is a call the snippet in the widget ? with a action or the widget instanciation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass this variable to `the_title()` but you can simply wrap it in [wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) function.

`echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), $number_of_words );`

Comment: thank you so much it worked. I have accepted your answer.